# Where can I find reliable information about Microsoft's plans for COM+ support in future versions of Windows?

Tags: windows, com+

When looking at a large web application with many competing priorities, one of the things I am faced with is a large number of COM+ components.  At some point, these things need to be re-engineered in some other technology (WCF, .NET, whatever).  Part of how I prioritize this effort will be "low long before Microsoft stops supporting it?"

I am having a devil of a time finding any solid officialy information from Microsoft with regard to what their current plans are for COM+ support in future versions of Windows.

Any guidance would be greatly aprpeciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have this information also :(.

Personally I don't believe that Microsoft is going to stop supporting COM/COM+ in the near future (just take a look in the # o components each Windows version introduces/depends on). To be sincere, I don't believe they can afford stop supporting COM+, ever.

IMHO, the more important question is how easy/expansive is to find qualified developers to maintain the code base.

Hope this helps